# Is there any built-in indentation option when logging object with serilog into file?

Tags: json, indentation, serilog

Is there any built-in indentation option when logging object with serilog into file, or should I use newtonSoft `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented)` etc.?

And what about XML indentation?

Comment: Logging to where? File? Console? Database?  Remember, serilog just logs "data".  Indentation is used when displaying data.  Are you looking for some way to format a file of serilog events?

Comment: to file. I edited the questoin. thanks